# Best natural way of coloring an icon/sprite

Tags: algorithm, graphics, colors

I wanna to color a sprite/icon with a transparent background and with shadows. I tried to shift the hue to all pixels but it looks not so natural and I have problems with the black and the white colors in an image. If an image tend to be black shifting the hue do not change the black in red or another color even shifting by 360 degrees. 
Tried to color addicting and subtracting color and even in that case the black and the white tend to be colored or disappears at all.

Maybe should I put an image on the icon to achieve the coloring effect ?
Any suggestions on how to proceed.
I lost.

Comment: Obviously hue shifting isn't going to affect black and white. (360 degree shift btw is the **same** hue). I'd open up some image editing software (e.g. GIMP) and see what you need do with "colorize"... starting with a 100% black image clearly you'll need to increase the lightness, maybe the saturation, and then choose hues.

Comment: Encrease the lightness and saturation do not solve the problem when the image predominant color is black or white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution by myself which can solve the problem with the black and white.

So basically the solution can be solved in multiple steps. Here I will define the steps. Later I'll provide some working code:

Get the image

Calculate the predominant color, averaging the image pixels or simply providing an input RGB value which is the predominant that your eye can catch.

If the predominant tends to be black or white, or both, the image has to be recolored with an addictive or subtractive method, addictive if black, subtractive if white. So basically all RGB pixels should be attenuated or sharpened until RED. I think that the best solution should be RED, because RED is first in the HUE scale, and this can help when we will hue-shift the pixels.

To have a unique algorithm which can work with different kind of images, not only black predominant or white, ideally the input the non-black and non-white predominant images should be pre-hueshifted manually, using photoshop or with another algorithm in a way that the new predominant color results to be RED too

After that the Hue shifting coloring is straighforward. We know that the predominant color is RED for all the images, and we'll shift the HUE values with a difference between the HSV value of the desired color and the HSV of the predominant color (RED).

Game over. We have a pretty universal way to color different images with hue shifting in a natural way.

Another question could be how to authomatically pre-shift the input images which predominant color is not black or white.
But this is another question.

Why this coloring method could be considered natural. Simply consider one thing. Generally  the non dominant black or white colors are part of the shadows and light which gives a 3D feel to the images. On the other hand if my shoes are 100% black and i will tint them with some colors, they will no more be black. Color the dominant black cannot be achieved simply shifting the HSV parameters but other steps should be performed. The steps are the above described.

Answer (score 1):

You've been asking a lot about this hue shifting thing, so I figured I'd try to work out an example: http://jsfiddle.net/EMujN/3/

Here's another that uses an actual icon: http://jsfiddle.net/EMujN/4/

There's a lot in there. There's a huge data URL which you can ignore unless you want to [replace it](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker). Here's the relevant part where we modify HSL.

```
    //SHIFT H HERE
    var hMod = .3;
    hsl[0]=(hsl[0]+hMod)%1;

    //MODIFY S HERE
    var sMod = .6;
    hsl[1]=Math.max(0,Math.min(1,
        hsl[1]+sMod
    ));

    //MODIFY L HERE
    var lMod = 0;
    hsl[2]=Math.max(0,Math.min(1,
        hsl[2]+lMod
    ));
```

I've converted to HSL because it's a lot easier to accomplish what you want in that color space than RGB.

Without getting any more complex, you have three variables you can tune: how much to add to either Hue, Saturation, or Lightness. I have the lightness variable set to 0 because any higher and you will see some nasty JPEG artifacts (if you can find a decent .png that would be better, but I went with the first CC night image I could find).

I think the hue shift (yellow to green) looks pretty good though and I have maxed out the saturation, so even a normally white light appears bright purple. Like I said in my comment, you will need to increase the lightness and saturation if you want to colorize patches of black and white. Hopefully, you can figure out what you need from this example.

image used: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Amman_(Jordan)_at_night.jpg

Comment: Basically the approach is clear but I'm not thinking about photis but icons sprites. The black is not the worst. The problem is that I wanna a general algorithm to regulate the hsv authomatically so it looks natural and it should be independent from the input. Another input is the predominant color.

Comment: I've posted an icon example in my answer. "a general algorithm to regulate the hsv authomatically so it looks natural" You're being quite vague. I don't think you've made clear yet what your actual problem is... I thought you were confused on hue shifting. Some examples of colorings that you don't think are "natural" and some more detail would help. "The black is not the worst." .... the first thing you said was you were having problems with black.

Comment: Yes it's a related thing. I wanna to color an image which predominant color may be black or any other color in the rgb. You told to me that I should regulate brightness and saturation too but I wanna the cpu do this for me